# how to bind json data to repeater control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, repeater

I've `Repeater` control and i want to bind it with data using ajax. For that I've created one handler which returns me a json data:

```
[{
    "OrderDetailID": 5,
    "OrderID": 5,
    "ProductWeightID": 945,
    "ProductName": "Real Choice Yogurt  5 kg",
    "NoOfCarton": 3.00,
    "ProductQuantity": 3,
    "OriginalPrice": 9.75,
    "OrderPrice": 9.75,
    "TotalPrice": 29.25
}]
```

I tried to bind data to repeater on ajax success(right now only for product name).

```
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../handlers/DisplaySpecificOrderDetail.ashx?OrderId=" + Orderid, //+ "tk=" + Date.toLocaleTimeString()
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: "true",
                    cache: "false",
                    success: function (data) {                          
                           $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                               alert(v.ProductName);
                               $(".prdName").html(v.ProductName);

                           });                      
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("fail");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                    });
         });
```

Here is `Repeater` control code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_ord_detail" runat="server">   
  <ItemTemplate>
     <table class="tbldetail">
       <tr>
         <td width="5%" class="center">
           <%# Convert.ToInt32(Container.ItemIndex + 1) %></td>
         <td class="prdName" width="25%"><%#  Eval("ProductName") %></td>
         <td width="12%" class="center"><%#  Eval("NoOfCarton") %></td>
         <td width="12%" class="center"><%# Eval("ProductQuantity") %></td>
         <td width="12%" class="center"><%# Eval("OriginalPrice") %></td>
         <td width="12%" class="center"><%# Eval("OrderPrice") %></td>
         <td width="10%" class="center"><%# Eval("Discount") %></td>
         <td width="12%" class="center"><%# Eval("TotalPrice") %></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But it's not displaying on repeater, and also not getting any error.

I missed something?

Comment: Repeater is a server-side control. It does not exist as a concept on a client side

Comment: @Andrei, So we can not bind data like I've tried? or is there any other why?

Comment: Update panel if you want to do this server side with repeater, javascript like jQuery tables if you prefer client side

Comment: @Andrei I've found something, like here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-Populate-Repeater-control-with-JSON-object-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: But seems not working in my case

Comment: Check out this link https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-Populate-Repeater-control-with-JSON-object-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx